# How to alert PHP echo in Javascript

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, html, ajax

Here i am validating the IP address entered in a textbox through PHP.

```
 $('#check_ip').click(function() {
 var iptext = $('#Ip_Txt').val();   
 $.ajax({
     type : "POST",
     url : "mypage.php",
     data : { iptext : iptext , testconn : "yes" },
     success : function(data) {                     
     }      
 });
 });
```

And my PHP

```
if(isset($_REQUEST['testconn'])){
if ( $_SERVER['REQUEST_METHOD'] == "POST" )
{
    $input = $_POST['iptext '];
    if (preg_match( "/^(([1-9]?[0-9]|1[0-9]{2}|2[0-4][0-9]|25[0-5]).){3}([1-9]?[0-9]|1[0-9]{2}|2[0-4][0-9]|25[0-5])$/", $input))
    {
        echo "Valid IP";
    }
    else
    {
        echo "Invalid IP";
    }
}   
}
```

Everything is working fine. But i need to display echo Valid IP or Invalid IP in javascript **alert** after clicking the check_ip button.

Comment: Check out [**this guide**](http://stackoverflow.com/q/23740548/) on SO.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No need to reinvent the wheel. You can use `filter_var()` on this one. Consider this example:

```
<?php

if($_SERVER['REQUEST_METHOD'] == 'POST') {
    $input_ip = $_POST['ip'];
    echo filter_var($input_ip, FILTER_VALIDATE_IP) ? 'Valid IP' : 'Not a valid IP';
    exit;
}

?>

<input type="text" id="ip_address" />
<button id="validate" type="button">Validate</button>

<script src="jquery.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
$(document).ready(function(){
    $('#validate').click(function(){
        var ip = $('#ip_address').val();
        $.ajax({
            url: 'index.php', // just same page sample
            type: 'POST',
            data: {ip: ip},
            success: function(response) {
                alert(response);
            }
        });
    });
});
</script>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can catch what ever response in sent from the server after completion of the request sent via ajax in success property. So inside your ajax success add this

```
success : function(data) { 
   alert(data);                    
}
```

Inside alert you can give what ever text you want. If you want to check what message needs to be displayed then do necessary checking's inside the success and then give the necessary messages

```
success : function(data) { 
   if(condition)
       alert('Some text');     
   else
       alert('Some other text');                   
}
```

Comment: I tried this. It is working... But i need a alert which display either valid or invalid only... i dont need complete data

Answer (score 0):

```
success: function(data) {
    alert(data);
}
```

Comment: alert() function takes string as arguements. data received on success callback is an object. your alert would display Object object or something like that

Answer (score 0):

The `data` is handling the echo from the backend so:

```
 $('#check_ip').click(function() {
     var iptext = $('#Ip_Txt').val();   
     $.ajax({
         type : "POST",
         url : "mypage.php",
         data : { iptext : iptext , testconn : "yes" },
         success : function(data) { 
             alert(data);           
         }      
     });
     });
```

Comment: This code is just the part of my page.. alert(data) will give me complete alert of my page... I need only Valid IP or Invalid IP. Thats it..

Comment: Do necessary checking and show the appropriate message in the alert

Answer (score 0):

```
$.ajax({
         type : "POST",
         url : "mypage.php",
         data : { iptext : iptext , testconn : "yes" },
         success : function(data) { 
             alert(data);           
         }      
     });
```

Just use alert method, pass the parameter into alert box

Comment: Thanks.. But how do i pass the parameter?

Comment: Whatever will be print in php file as it is will show in the alert box. Example : According to your script result can be 'Valid IP' or 'Invalid IP'

Answer (score 0):

```
success : function(data) { 
   var response_string = JSON.stringify( data );
   // do your substr operations here
   alert( your_substring );                    
}
```

JSON.stringify converts your response to string. you can then perform any string operations you like on it.

Happy coding :)